# Separable metric space and discontinuouty point of the function defined on it

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show the following:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space and $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be a function such that, for every point $x\in X$, $\,\,\,$ $lim_{t\to x}f(t)$ exist. consider:
>
> $A=\{x\in X; f\,\,is \,\, discontinuous \,\, at \,\,x \}$
>
> Prove that $A$ is countable.

I defined:

$$\omega(x)=lim_{\delta\to 0^+}(sup\{f(t);t\in B(\delta,x)\}-inf\{f(t);t\in B(\delta,x)\})$$

Wich:

$$B(\delta,x)=\{y\in X;\, d(x,y)\lt \delta\}$$

It's trivial that $f$ at the point $x\in X$ is discontinuous iff $\omega(x)\gt 0$ Now define:

$$D_n=\{x\in X ;\, \omega(x)\gt \frac{1}{n}\}$$

Then:

$$A=\cup_{n}^{\infty} D_n$$

How I can prove that every $D_n$ is countable?

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can prove that every $D_n$ is countable?

By showing that it is a closed and discrete subspace of $X$.

Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $x\in X$. By the existence of the limit $\ell := \lim\limits_{t\to x} f(t)$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t\in B(\delta,x)\setminus \{x\}$ we have $\lvert f(t) - \ell\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{3n}$. It follows that $\omega(t) \leqslant \frac{2}{3n} < \frac{1}{n}$ for $t\in B(\delta,x)\setminus \{x\}$, and therefore

$$D_n \cap B(\delta,x) \subset \{x\}.$$

This means $D_n$ is a closed and discrete subspace of $X$, and since $X$ is separable, it follows that $D_n$ is (at most) countable.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $$A=\{t\in X : \lim_{v\to t} f(v) <f(t) \}$$ and $$B=\{t\in X: \lim_{v\to t} f(v) >f(t) \}.$$ 
For each $\delta >0$, the set $V_{\delta}$ of all $x\in X$ such that $f(y)<f(x)$ for all $y$ with $0<d(x,y)<\delta$ is countable. To see this let $\left(B\left(x_n , \frac{\delta }{2}\right)\right)$ be a cover of $X$ with open balls of radius $\frac{\delta}{2} $ then $\mbox{card}\left(V_{\delta}\cap B\left(x_n , \frac{\delta }{2} \right)\right)\leqslant 1 $ for each $n.$  The set $V$ of strict local maxima is a countable union of such sets $V_{\delta}$ for each $n$, for example taking $\delta =\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ ranges over the natural numbers. Hence the set $V$ is countable. Therefore the set $A$ is a countable as a subset of $V.$
Analogously the set $U$ of strict local minima is countable hence $B\subset U$ is also a countable set.
Finally the set of discontinouities of $f$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ hence countable.